# Web Api route filter to sub directory

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-routing

Inside my Controllers directory I have two sub directories - FeaturesA and FeaturesB

```
FeaturesA
      Service1Controller 
      Service2Controller 
      Service3Controller

FeaturesB 
      Service4Controller
      Service5Controller
      Service6Controller
```

I want to add two routes so that I can access these services via the following URLs -

```
localhost/api/FeaturesA/....
```

and

```
localhost/api/FeaturesB/....
```

I have the follwing route setup

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
           name: "FeaturesA",
           routeTemplate: "api/FeaturesA/{controller}/{id}",
           defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional});

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
           name: "FeaturesB",
           routeTemplate: "api/FeaturesB/{controller}/{id}",
           defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional});
```

BUT I can access Service1 from `localhost/api/FeaturesA/Service1` and `localhost/api/FeaturesB/Service1` and even `localhost/api/Service1`

How do I setup my routes to only allow Service1 to accessed from `localhost/api/FeaturesA/Service1`, same applies to all the other controllers, i.e. they should only be accessible from a url which matches their controller sub dir.

Comment: there was another answer to this question that had very useful information, could the contributor please repost that answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems like pretty much exactly what [routing constraints](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.routing.irouteconstraint.aspx) were introduced to accomplish. If you have a simple enough case, you could use the built-in types to just add regular expressions to match against the controller names. But for more complex cases, you could write your own.

Pinal Bhatt has a nice blog post with links to a bunch of articles on the subject here: http://blog.pbdesk.com/2012/07/route-constraints-with-aspnet-mvc.html

Comment: Thanks, adding this to the route does what I want - constraints: new { controller = "service1|service2|service3" }